# SAS - Flag if variable is present in another column of same dataset

Tags: sas, comparison

I have a SAS dataset with 2 columns that I want to compare (VAR1 and VAR2). I would like to check if for each value of VAR1 this value exists anywhere in the column VAR2. If the VAR1 value does not exist anywhere in the column VAR2 I want to flag it as 1.
For exemple :

I have this :

TABLE in

| VAR1 | VAR2 |
| --- | --- |
| k3 | t7 |
| t7 | g7 |
| p8 | k3 |
| ... | ... |

And would want this

TABLE out

| VAR1 | VAR2 | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| k3 | t7 | 0 |
| t7 | g7 | 0 |
| p8 | k3 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I tried using

> FLAG = ifn(indexw(VAR2,VAR1,0,1)

But this method only compare the two columns for the current row.

Thank you in advance for your help !

**Edit : I tried running this code as suggested by Joe but ran into an error.**

Code :

```
data your_table;
   length VAR1 $2; 
   length VAR2 $2;
   input VAR1 VAR2;   
   datalines;          
k3 t7
t7 g7
p8 k3
;                      

data for_fmt;
  set your_table;
  fmtname = 'VAR2F';
  start = var2;
  label = '0';
  output;
  if _n_ eq 1 then do;
    hlo = 'o';   
    start = .;
    label = '1';
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort nodupkey data=for_fmt;
by start;
run;

proc format cntlin=for_fmt;
quit;

data want;
  set your_table;
  flag = put(var1,var2f.);
run;
```

Error:

```
ERROR: This range is repeated, or values overlap:            .-           ..
```

Answer (score 1):

In SAS, everything is based on one row at a time in the data step, so you can't do what you're looking to directly.

What you can do, though, is use a lookup technique - there are quite a few - and that will let you get what you're after.

The easiest one to use in your case is probably a format.

```
data for_fmt;
  set your_table;
  fmtname = 'VAR2F';
  start = var2;
  label = '0';
  output;
  if _n_ eq 1 then do;
    hlo = 'o';   *this is for "other" (not found) records;
    start = .;
    label = '1';
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort nodupkey data=for_fmt;
by start;
run;

proc format cntlin=for_fmt;
quit;


data want;
  set your_table;
  flag = put(var1,var2f.);
run;
```

This is pretty fast (only limited by dataset read/write time) unless you have millions of unique rows.

You could also merge the dataset to itself, or do this in SQL, or use a hash table, but the format approach is probably simplest.

Comment: Thank you for your response Joe. 
Unfortunately I get an error while running your exact code with the exact input table from my example. I am not familiar with lookup methods and just wanted to test it out to see what would happen.

The code I ran is just before yours is : 
data your_table;
   length VAR1 $2; 
   length VAR2 $2;
   input VAR1 VAR2;   
   datalines;          
k3 t7
t7 g7
p8 k3
;

Comment: Please put code into the question - that would make answering this easier for everyone.

Comment: Ok sorry I'm not familiar with the website, thank you for your help I added It

Comment: @Pwavre The code is developed for numeric VAR1 and VAR2. It needs a little modification to apply for character situation. Add `$` before you define and use the format `var2f`: `fmtname = '$VAR2F'` and `flag = put(var1,$var2f.)`

Answer (score 0):

As @Joe says, it is always on one row at a time in the data step. So if you can make all possible value of var1 in one row, you can do the character match work easily.

```
data your_table;
   length VAR1 $2; 
   length VAR2 $2;
   input VAR1 VAR2;   
   datalines;          
k3 t7
t7 g7
p8 k3
;                      

data want;

  array _char_[&sysnobs.]$200._temporary_;
  do until(eof1);
    set your_table end=eof1;
    i+1;
    _char_[i]=var2;
  end;

  do until(eof2);
    set your_table end=eof2;
    flag=1;
    do i=1to dim(_char_) until(flag=0);
      if var1=_char_[i] then flag=0;
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I typically use in situations like this. I first create a list of the variables to check against, then merge with that and can easily pick out the ones that are found.

```
proc sort data=have (keep=var2) out=var2levels (rename=(var2=var1)) nodupkey; by var2;
proc sort data=have; by var1;

data want;
  merge have (in=in1) var2levels (in=in2);
  by var1;
  if in1;
  flag = in2;
run;
```

So here the first proc sort creates a list of all the unique values of var2. The output data set renames that to var1 for merging purposes (this can be done more clearly but less efficiently by renaming multiple variables).  Then we simply merge the original data set (keeping all records) with the list of existing var2 values and set the flag accordingly.